# Keeping validation errors after redirect from partial back to the same page that has the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to get the errors from my form that is rendered as a partial inside my root_path. After I attempt to post it, and it fails (or succeeds), I want to redirect back to the root_path. However, redirect_to decides to not save any information for the validation.

Wondering how to do this.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @nom = current_user.noms.build(params[:nom])
    if @nom.save
      flash[:success] = "Nom created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @nom.errors
      redirect_to root_path
  end
```

In my Home/Index, I render the partial for the form of the post.

```
= form_for [current_user, @post] do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.select :category
  = f.text_area :description
  = f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary"

  - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    %p
      = msg
```

It should be keeping the errors at the bottom of the form after it redirects to the root_path.

I'd also like to keep the information that was there after the validation failed.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use redirect in this case, instead use render:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  #..

  def create
    @nom = current_user.noms.build(params[:nom])
    if @nom.save
      flash[:success] = "Nom created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @nom.errors
      render :template => "controller/index"
    end
  end
```

Replace `controller/index` with names of you controller and action

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller)

Comment: While that kind of works... the problem is it only re-renders the partial and not the full page. Also, it seems to redirect to the user/1/posts.

Comment: I'm not sure `redirect_to root_path and return` is working the way I'd like it to.
I want it to go back to the root_path meaning home/index after attempting to post the Post from the partial form that's on the root_path. When I `render template: '/home/index'` it works, but it goes to 'user/1/posts', where I just want it to go back to the root_path, so... '/'

Comment: Yep, if its problem for you than mb try with `= form_for [current_user, @post], :remote => true do |f|` in the form. But you should implement some logic in create action with respond_to js.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me

```
format.html { redirect_to :back, flash: {:errors => "Document "+@requested_doc.errors.messages[:document][0] }}
```

I don't know if this could cause any other exception issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use **redirect_to** for showing the error messages of an object because while redirecting it discards your object which does have linked with the error_messages & took a new object to redirect the path.

So in that case, you only have to use **render**.

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html { 
          flash[:error] = @account.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
          render "edit", :id => @account._id, sid: @account.site._id
        }
end
```