# Rails controller action duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, renderpartial, deduplication

I have a controller show action which does some stuff and renders a view but due to some custom routing, I need a totally different action in a totally different controller to perform the same stuff and render the same view.

I don't really wish to duplicate the code. Is there somewhere I can put it and call it from both locations?

Edit:

I basically need to run the following from Collection#Show AND also from Gallery#SplitUrl:

```
@collection = Collection.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @collection.has_children?
  @collections = @collection.children
else
  redirect_to [@collection, :albums]
end
```

I cannot just `redirect_to` Collection#Show at the end of Gallery#SplitUrl as the redirect causes my custom URL's to be lost as it's a new request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller

Answer (score 0):

You could put the view content into a partial `(/app/views/home/_example.html.erb)` and then use the `render "example"` command in the HomeController.

The "some stuff" code you talk about could be put into a helper file `/app/helpers/...` to save you from duplicating code in the two separate controllers although it could depend on what the code is trying to do in the first place.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

This might provide more information on the subject in general.

Comment: I've added more info in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach would be to add a route definition for your new `url` and map that to your existing `controller`'s `action`.

Something like follows:

```
# config/routes.rb

# Existing resource
resources :foos

# The resource in question
resources :bars do 
  get :show, controller: 'foos', action: 'show', as: bar_foo_common_show
end
```

Note that this will give you `/bar/:id`, where `id` represents a `bar` resource.  So in your `foo#show` action, your finder needs to be executed on appropriate class.  This is when a few lines of hacky codes get added, for e.g. checking for request referer.

I think moving the common code to a function in possibly `application_controller` and calling that function from both `show` action would be cleaner approach, but based on my understanding you already have a similar scenario except for the common code in `application_controller`, and would like to try out a different approach!

Comment: The reason is, is that I have a route that for my photo gallery routes to Gallery#SplitUrl this should then split the url on the "/" and figure out what the user is trying to access as I want Url's like /gallery/collection1name/collection2name/collection3name/album1name  The models I have are Collection, Album and Photo and Collection is a self referential model so a Collection can contain other collections or albums but never both at the same time.  Any ideas?