# Rails controller redirect_to an action with params without key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I would like to redirect from one action to another in a same controller.

Suppose I have a private method `my_params` that returns an `ActionController::Parameters` instance. It looks like `{ some_param: 'a', another_param: 'b' }`.

Let's say I want to redirect from `:action_1` from `:action_2` passing `params`.

When I try to do `redirect_to :action, my_params`, Rails complains:

```
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Normally, I would write something like,

```
redirect_to :action, some_param: 'a', another_param: 'b'`
```

but I cannot do so in this case, because I want to pass `my_params`.

Is there a Rails way to do this? Or any other suggestions?

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate because I want to pass in a param that is already an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: call another controller action from a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your current `my_params` parameters hash to the `redirect_to` method and only update (`merge`) the values you want to change.

```
redirect_to my_params.merge(action: :action_1)
```