# Rails: Rendering a template in a different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

**How can I render an action of a controller which is in a different namespace?**

For example, if I have a login controller in a Webapp namespace `Webapp::LoginController` and I want to render the index action (not a partial!) in an events controller in the API namespace `API::EventsController` if the user is logged in:

```
class Webapp::LoginController < ApplicationController
  include Webapp::LoginHelper
  def index
    render 'events/index' if logged_in? # events#index is in the API namespace
   end
end
```

**Is this even possible**? I see the answer being no because of potential conflicts with subdomains and paths, depending on how the routes are defined.

I know **I could redirect** to the page I'd like with

```
redirect_to api_events_url
```

but this will create a new request which I don't necessarily want.

Comment: have you tried this `render action: 'events/index'`

Comment: Yes, this won't work, as this refers to actions in the same controller. But you gave me the idea to a different approach, trying to render the file on the path (`render "/vagrant/app/views/api/events/index"`). Interestingly, it won't find the file there: `Missing template app/views/api/events/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/vagrant/app/views" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
render 'api/events/index'
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I originally thought this would render a partial, since it threw an undefined method error on one. What I missed was that a partial used by the template I called required some variables to be set by the events controller, hence the error on the partial. For future reference, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller) lines out some DRY ways to reuse the API Controller code (i like apneadiving's answer) - which is not recommended since it neglects the MVC concept. Other possibility: helper methods.