# Call Create Action in other Controller API using Repost ruby gems got template not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have 2 controller API, A and B on Ruby on rails application. If the parameter passed the validation in controller A, it will redirect to `create` action on controller B. If it is not, then continue to run the logic on controller A.

At first, I try using `redirect_to`, but since the action is using POST method, it doesn't work. Then I try to use `repost` ruby gems, from https://rubygems.org/gems/repost.
I have followed the documentation, but when I test the API, it returns `No template found for xxxController#create, rendering head :no_content`. Since it is an API, I think it doesn't need view.

I have tried to add view for that controller, but it ends up rendering the html to the response. Anyone have an idea to make it redirect to other controller? Or any other ways to solve this using other gems maybe?

EDIT
I also try to render the html this way:

```
render html: Repost::Senpai.perform('http://xxx', params: { auth: request.params[:user] }, options: {authenticity_token: :auto, autosubmit: true}).html_safe, status: status
```

I copy the logic from the gem repo in https://github.com/vergilet/repost/blob/master/lib/repost/extend_controller.rb. But still, the html just rendered to the response. It doesn't redirect to given url

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism that makes `repost` work is that it's rendering an HTML form and auto-submitting it. Just calling `Repost::Senpai.perform` alone won't render the HTML.

You could try the following. It's based on repost's [extension for ActionController::Base](https://github.com/vergilet/repost/blob/master/lib/repost/extend_controller.rb)

```
render html: Repost::Senpai.perform(
  'http://xxxx',
  params: { auth: request.params[:user] },
).html_safe, status: :ok
```

Comment: when I used `repost`, I got `undefined method 'repost'` error. And refer to the answer in github issue https://github.com/vergilet/repost/issues/13, he said that if we use `ActionController::API` then we need to use Senpai, because `repost` is only for `ActionController::Base`

Comment: @Intan updated my answer - though I'm not sure if that will work. Using an API controller doesn't really make sense here because `repost` requires an HTML form to be rendered

Comment: I tried it, but it still won't redirect to the other API controller. The html from `Repost::Senpai.perform` is rendered to the response

Comment: @Intan yeah, it's not going to work. Repost creates an HTML form and then uses javascript to submit it.

Comment: @Intan an alternative method would be to call the controller_b.process(:create) from controller A instead of trying to do it as a redirect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller